# How can be made a matrix containing empty arrays?

Tags: arrays, julia

Is there any possibility in Julia to have a matrix including an empty array as its element, for example as follow:

```
Alpha=zeros([],3,3)
```

The first element of `Alpha` is an array whose dimension isn't determined. But it gets error.
Would you please help me that how can I attain the matrix.

Comment: I am not fully clear what you need, but probably `Alpha = [[] for i in 1:3, j in 1:3]`. This expression makes sure that `Alpha` is initially populated and 2) the entries of `Alpha` do not share the same data. Note that this will be inefficient in general though as `[]` will have `Any` eltype.

Comment: Thanks very much. the elements of `[]` are Integer between 1:10.  `Alpha = [Int8[]    for i in 1:totalV, k in 1:totalk, j in 1:totalH]` is it  suitable for defining that matrix?

Comment: the parameters are :`totalk=3 , totalV=6, totalH=3`

Comment: Yes, it will be a 3-dimensional array then. You can also simply write `Int[]`, as probably you do not have to minimize memory footprint of your data structure given the parameter values you have given.

Comment: One thing: are you sure you don't just want a 3d array? `array{Int8, 3}(undef, i, j ,k) might be what you didn't know you were looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just putting this here for posterity. Based on the comments, it sounds like you are either looking for an array of uninitialized arrays of type `Int` (Bogumil's comment):

```
alpha = [Int[] for i in 1:total_i, j in 1:total_j]  # etc. for however many dimensions
```

or you are looking for an n-dimensional array of type `Int` (Oscar's comment). For instance, a 3-dimensional array:

```
alpha = array{Int, 3}(undef, total_i, total_j, total_k)
```

Just wanted to collate the comments section into an answer in case somebody comes looking and doesn't notice the comments.